# Insert Environment Variables into Jetty web.xml or quickstart.xml

Tags: java, xml, jetty, web.xml, jetty-9

Inside my web.xml and quickstart.xml, I want to be able to substitute a ip with a defined value from my machine's environment variables. is this possible?

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
    <param-value>https://192.168.1.2/cas/login</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>serverName</param-name>
    <param-value>https://192.168.1.2:443</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For example, I'd like to be able to put in my environment variables casip=192.168.1.2 and have it be passed into my web.xml or quickstart.xml.

The reason why I want this is I need the variable to be exposed (ie environmental variables) so that ansible can change it during an installation since the entire webapp will be wrapped within a docker container.

Comment: Idk if you can do that, but several dockerized applications I've seen simply build config files in their start script. E.g. using `sed` to replace placeholders in a xml file with environment variables. (e.g. https://theagileadmin.com/2015/11/12/templating-config-files-in-docker-containers/)

Comment: Hmm would that take away from the startup speed of the container?

An alternative that came to mind is to edit /etc/hosts and then have ansible user docker-compose to control that. I'm not sure which method would be better though.

Comment: well, microseconds or so

Comment: I guess I'll have to test it. Some of my webapps only need single replacements. Others need a lot more (100+). My other concern would be scalability. This file is outputted from a war file which may change at anytime. If more entries were added, I'd then have to go and manually insert those.

Comment: @zapl I think your method is probably the way to go. Turns out that the filter isn't doing any of the trafficking, it's just redirecting the request which doesn't help if the other system can't resolve the hostname.